# How to test that related object receives a method call in an after_save callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a simple model that has an `after_save` callback to update some things on a related model when the status changes:

```rb
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :related_records
  after_update :check_change
  enum :status { 'status1', 'status2'}

  def check_change
    return unless saved_change_to_status?

    related_records.each(&:schedule_email)
  end
```

Now I'd like to test this method with Rspec. I first tested whether the method gets called, which succeeds:

```rb
it "should be called"
  expect(subject).to receive(:check_change)
  subject.save
end
```

Now I'd like to check whether each of the related records receives the `schedule_email` method:

```rb
  it 'should call method on related records' do
    subject.update(status: 'status2')
    subject.emails.each do |msg|
      expect(msg).to receive(:schedule_email)
    end
  end
```

Somehow this doesn't work. I also tried calling the `update` after the expect without any luck. I can't get my head around what is going wrong. Any ideas?

Edit: I also created a break point after the guard clause in the method. During the test it stops execution, so I'm assuming that the schedule_email method is being called on all related records... should I `expect` in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

`expect(msg).to receive(:schedule_email)` should go BEFORE actual test call, to set message expectations properly. So it would rather be:

```
it 'should call method on related records' do
  subject.emails.each do |msg|
    expect(msg).to receive(:schedule_email)
  end
  subject.update(status: 'status2')
end
```

Comment: I tested that as well... but still no luck :(

Comment: I refactored the `related_records.each(&:schedule_email)` part into it's own (private) method, called `schedule_emails` when I `expect(subject).to receive(:schedule_emails)`, it passes. Unfortunately this still doesn't let me test the functionality of the method.